# Adding Google fonts with different weights to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, google-font-api

I can add Google fonts to CKEditor easy enough by including the config.contentsCss with the font list and the setting config.font_names in config.js

However,  where I am stuck is how to add a font with different weights.

For example,  lets assume I want to include Open Sans in 400,700 and 800 weights.

So, firstly, I add this line to config.js :

```
config.contentsCss = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400|Open+Sans:700|Open+Sans:800';
```

Now, I want to be able to add all 3 weights and call them, say, Open Sans Normal, Open Sans Bold and Open Sans Extra Bold.

To include the normal (400 weight) font I can use :

```
config.font_names = config.font_names + 'Open Sans/Open Sans;';
```

But how would I include the others ?  I have tried :

```
config.font_names = config.font_names + 'Open Sans Bold/Open Sans:700;';
```

But, of course, it didn't work - any ideas much appreciated please

Answer (score -1):

CKEditor sets <span style="font-family: YourFontName">Lorem ipsum</span>

As you can see in the source of http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400|Open+Sans:700|Open+Sans:800 the family name of all 3 fonts are the same.

I would say, the easiest way is to copy the source to your own CSS file and change the family names to 3 different ones.

Comment: IF you do that, make sure to figure out how to solve X-Browser compatibility. The CSS depends on the User Agent and contains completely different font formats. You can create a X-Browser CSS definition with http://localfont.com